# Refactor sql query from source code

Tags: c#, .net, sql, refactoring

I have a method which contains a very big sql query directly in the .CS file. What would the recommended refactoring method be?

Comment: Move the database code where it belongs to... create a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the large complex SQL query into a SQL View or Stored Procedure, and just use that in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use stored procedure

```
string commandText = "SP_Your_Sp_Name";

using (SqlConnection objSqlConnection = Connection)

{

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, objSqlConnection))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parameter_Name", value));
        if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
        }
        result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is creating store procedure on the server is not that easy (for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

Use a stored procedure.
In this case the query execution will be faster when the execution plan  is stored in the cache.